# column number to be automate with specified value

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a few columns

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:\data_ana\\10.05.43.csv')

cols_in_the_slice = df.loc[:,(' Objects[0].MeasuredTimeStamp',
                          ' Objects[0].LifeCycles',
                          ' Objects[0].KinematicRel.f_DistX',
                          ' Objects[0].KinematicRel.f_DistY',
                         ' Objects[0].KinematicRel.f_VrelX',
                         ' Objects[0].KinematicRel.f_VrelY',
                         ' Objects[0].KinematicAbs.f_VabsX',
                        'Objects[0].KinematicAbs.f_VabsY',
                        'Objects[0].SensorSpecific.f_RCS',
                        'Objects[0].CurrentTarget.f_DistX',
                       ' Objects[0].CurrentTarget.f_DistY',
                       'Objects[0].CurrentTarget.f_VrelX',
                       'Objects[0].CurrentTarget.f_VrelY',
                       'Objects[0].CurrentTarget.f_RCS')].columns
```

I have these columns
here I am manually entering he number for each column for eg If I want to enter the number 1 , then I have to change manually from Objects[0].MeasuredTimeStamp',
' Objects[0].LifeCycles' to   Objects[1].MeasuredTimeStamp',
' Objects[1].LifeCycles' so on...

How can I automate this giving a random number to first column and it will be same for other column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working with strings, you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).  Below is an example. Note the `...` should be replaced with all the other columns:

```
index = 3
cols_in_the_slice = df.loc[:, 
                          (f'Objects[{index}].MeasuredTimeStamp',
                           ..., 
                           f'Objects[{index}].CurrentTarget.f_RCS')].columns
```

As you have stated that you wish to assign a random number, you can set the index using the `randint` function of the `random` module.

You can learn more about this here: [generating pseudo-random numbers in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

You will need to specify the range for the random number. Here is an example of how to generate an index between 0 and 10 (inclusive):

```
import random

index = random.randint(0, 10)
```